# storing and processing word families in Evil Hangman game using c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am writing a program for EVIL HANGMAN in C++. 
I have English dictionary in a text file.

Steps of algorithm executed uptil now are::

(1) player chooses the length of the word.
(a new txt file is created with all words of length = 4. Let's call it "**SelectedWords.txt**")
(2) player chooses the number of attempts.
(3) Player gives a alphabet as a choice.

e.g According to step 1, if chosen length=4 then SelectedWords.txt will look like:

---

> ALLY
>   BETA
>   COOL
>   DEAL
>   ELSE
>   FLEW
>   GOOD
>   HOPE

---

3rd step: If chosen letter is "E" then word families would look as:

_ _ _ _(ALLY,COOL,GOOD)
_ E _ _(BETA,DEAL)
_ _ E _(FLEW)
_ _ _ E(HOPE)

I've executed step 2 perfectly and step 3 partially.

In step 3, I've to choose from "SelectedWords.txt" words falling in similar word families and then count them. (I am planning to use 2D string array for saving words with similar family). I have to choose the word family with maximum words and discard rest of all families. What approach should i take up?

Thank you for reading this long.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to take `std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >` where the outer vector stores the families and the inner vectors the words contained in the families. You would use it as following (simplified, every word contains max. one occurrence of the specific letter):

```
int word_length = 4;
vector< vector<string> > families(word_length+1,vector(0,string()));
/* parse your .txt file or the previous list here and insert words in the appropriate vector contained by family */
/* that means if the letter is at the n-th position you insert in families[n], if the letter is not contained it comes in families[0] */
//checking for the largest family:
unsigned int max = 0, max_index;
for(unsigned int ii=0; ii<families.size(); ii++)
{
    if(families[ii].size() > max) {
        max = families[ii].size();
        max_index = ii;
    }
}
//then you keep the vector at position max_index and this will be the starting point for estimating subsequent families;
```

Since you can also have more than only one occurrence of a letter in a word you would have to extend the size of your family vector. To get the number of possible occurrences you can use the binomial coefficient (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and sum them up for all numbers of occurrences (i.e. from 1 to word_length-1, since a word won't consist of only one letter). Here you have to be sure about the ordering within your family vector (first no occurrence then all 1-occurrences, then all 2-, and so on).

Alternatively you can use `std::map` and use `std::tupel` as key and `std::vector<std::string>` as value. The tupel would be a `N-tupel` if N is the length of the word. By using `std::tupel<bool>` a `tupel` would save if there is an 'E' at first place, second place and so on. For example (f means false, t means true): "ALLY" corresponds to the family `(f,f,f,f)` since every letter is not an 'E'. "BETA" corresponds to `(f,t,f,f)` and "FLEW" to `(f,f,t,f)` and so on. For every word you create the corresponding `tupel` and insert the word using the `tupel` as a key at the appropriate position in your `map` (which is families).

EDIT: I'm not one hundred percent sure but it might be the case that tuples cannot be used as keys for std::map since they are non-hashable objects (where hashing the keys is required to provide a fast look-up within the map). Alternatively you can use std::string as a key using the same idea. Instead of a tuple `(f,f,f,f)` you would simply take `"0000"` and `(f,t,f,f)` would go to `"0100"` and so on. Here you don't have to use `1`s and `0`s but you can use any *encoding* you wish (e.g. `"False,True,False,False"` or something similar).